# Модуль plot из пакета Sympy не рисует график

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
x = symbols('x')
plot((x - 2), (x, 0, 10))
```

Comment: Скажи, пожалуйста, а `matplotlib` установлен?

Comment: matplotib 1.5.3 and  sympy 1.1  are installed and working.

Comment: вы запускаете это как скрипт или как набор команд в какой-то среде (ipython, Jupyter, etc.)?

Comment: Код запускаю как скрипт, через IDLE.

Comment: Выдаёт следующую ошибку: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\11111.py", line 5, in <module>
    plot((x - 2), (x, 0, 10))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 980, in process_series....
    Axes3D = mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mplot3d'
>>> `